# populate struct fields in Go by looping over data from another function

Tags: for-loop, go, struct

I have a couple handlers in a web app (Fiber framework) where one handler retrieves data from an external API and the other handler takes a subset of this data and performs some business logic (ie sends a report, etc).

Both handlers are in the same package. In handler2.go I am able to dereference the data from handler1.go and I want to use specific values from that data to populate the struct fields in handler2.go. The dereferenced data from handler1.go is itself an array of structs that I can loop over.

In handler2.go , I have a struct:

```
type Report struct {
  contact  string
  date     string
  resource string
}

// get data from handler1.go function and use it to populate the Report struct
// each "report" is a struct, so need to create a list of structs
func getReportData() {
   reportData := GetReport() // call function in handler1.go
   for _, report := range *reportData {
   fmt.Println(report.Date)
}
```

So instead of simply printing the data (the print statement is just to show that I have access to the data I need) I want to populate the Report struct with specifc items from the data that I can can access using the loop and the `report.<KEY>` syntax.

How can I create a list of structs (using the Report struct)  populated with the data I can get via this `for` loop?

For an MVP , I can simply format this list of structs (in json) and display an endpoint in the web app. I am just struggling with how to construct this data properly.

Comment: What does `GetReport` output?  If JSON, then you should write a GetReportData function separate from GetReportJson so you don't have to json encode then decode the data

Comment: What data type is returned by `GetReport()`? If it already has `Date`, `Contact`, and `Resource` fields, do you really need to convert the result into your `Report` struct? Or could you just replace `getReportData()` with the call to `GetReport()`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please try to be more to the point. What's the input, what's the desired output, what have you tried, what error did you get.

Comment: Sorry I should made that more clear, the GetReport() function calls a func that is in another handler in the same package. That function has called an external API and returned a large set of structured json data.  In the 2nd handler (the one in my question code) I need to extract just a few fields from the orignal function's return (json)  and then perform busines logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the direct question, if we assume that the values returned by `GetReport()` have `Date`, `Contact`, and `Resource` fields, then you could write:

```
type Report struct {
  contact  string
  date     string
  resource string
}

// Return a list (well, slice) of Reports
func getReportData() (reports []Report) {
  reportData := GetReport()
  for _, report := range reportData {
    myReport := Report{
      contact:  report.Contact,
      date:     report.Date,
      resource: report.Resource,
    }

    reports = append(reports, myReport)
  }

  return
}
```

Comment: Though this will not produce any useful JSON for the MVP that OP mentioned since the fields are unexported.

Comment: I mean, this won't produce JSON *at all* because that's not what the code is demonstrating. As you said in a comment on the question, it's not entirely clear what the OP is looking for, so I figured this would either (a) help, or at least (b) provide a starting point for clarifying the question.

Comment: yes, please see my comment above, I should have mentioned this was all about structured json data: retrieving it from handler1 and then producting it here in handler2. My post did not include any code for generating json. I was just stuck on how to get all the data assembled in this handler.

Comment: @RobertCampbell I'm still unclear as to whether or not the example provided here addresses your question, and if not, what exactly is missing. I think this directly addresses the question, "How can I create a list of structs (using the Report struct) populated with the data I can get via this for loop?", but perhaps I am misreading things?

Comment: yes , the code in the answer looks to be exactly what I was lookng to do